# What requirements does a router need to fulfill to support a network of 50 miners?

Tags: mining-hardware, network, mining-setup, memory

I am running a network with fifty miners, and I am experiencing network problems with my current router from ASUS, because its memory fills up and it requires to restart in order to work properly. I want to get a better router to fix that issue.

What should I look out for when deciding what router to buy to support a network with 50 miners?

Comment: Hi Toka, I've touched-up your question to move it away from asking for a product recommendation toward asking general advice on deciding the issue yourself. I did so, because product recommendations are off-topic. Hope that you get the information that you need. :)